# What is a way to create a large matrix of smaller matrices with varying parameters

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix which has dimension *5*-by-*4* whose elements are a function of 2 parameters `beta1` and `beta2`, which takes on 50 values each.

The *5*-by-*4* matrix has the form

```
for i=1:5
   factors(i,:)=  [1,...
                  1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1) /(terms(i)/beta1), ...
                  (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1))/(terms(i)/beta1)-exp(-terms(i)/beta1), ...
                  (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta2))/(terms(i)/beta2)-exp(-terms(i)/beta2)];
end
```

I want to create a larger matrix whose columns contain 50 of the *5*-by-*4* matrices with varying `beta1` and fixed `beta2`. The rows contain 50 of the *5*-by-*4* matrices with varying `beta2` and fixed `beta1`. So the dimensions of the larger matrix are *250*-by-*200*.

Is there a function or loop which can help me with this? I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: How are the elements function of  beta? you have a function()?

Comment: for i=1:5
factors(i,:)=[1, (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1)/(terms(i)/beta1)), (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1))/ (terms(i)/beta1)-exp(-terms(i)/beta1), (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta2))/(terms(i)/beta2)-exp(-terms(i)/beta2)];
end

Comment: Do you simply need to replicate the 5 by 4 matrix 50 times and stack them together? Or do each element of the larger matrix need to be re-evaluated by your function? i.e. your function should now be i = 1:250 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have or can write a function that accepts two parameters and output your *5*-by-*4* matrix i.e.

```
function m = f(beta1, beta2) %// You must write f yourself. m is a 5-by-4 matrix
```

then the simplest solution would just be to create a nested loop (preallocating for efficiency of course). Note that I am also assuming you know how you want to vary `beta1` and `beta2` and that you will put these in *50*-by-*1* vectors `B1` and `B2` yourself:

```
M = zeros(250,200);
b1 = 1;
for r = 1:5:(250-5)
    b2 = 1;
    for c = 1:4:(200-4)
        M(r:r+4,c:c+3) = f(B1(b1), B2(b2));
        b2 = b2+1;
    end
    b1 = b1+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Say I have a value that depends on 2 other values.  I can write a function to calculate this say `myfun = @(x,y) x + y`.  I can use that with arrayfun or bsxfun, etc to rapidly calculate values for all `x`'s and `y`'s.

```
x = rand(1000,1);
y = rand(1000,1);
res = arrayfun(myfun, x, y);
```

In your case you need to define `terms` ahead of time and then vary `beta1` and `beta2` as desired.  One thing to look out for is that arrayfun wants all the variables to be of the same size so use repmat or similar to reshape beta1 and beta2.  For example

```
terms = 1:5;
i = 1:5;
myfun = @(beta1, beta2) [1, (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1)/(terms(i)/beta1)), (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta1))/ (terms(i)/beta1)-exp(-terms(i)/beta1), (1-exp(-terms(i)/beta2))/(terms(i)/beta2)-exp(-terms(i)/beta2)];
beta1 = repmat(rand(1,1),1,5);
beta2 = repmat(rand(1,1),1,5);
results = arrayfun(myfun, beta1, beta2,i,'UniformOutput',0);
```

The output of this will be a cell of arrays.  I believe under the hood arrayfun is just a loop but it should be vectorized by MathWorks so it should be fast.

To create varying beta1 and fixed beta2 just define them as such were beta1 varies for the first half of the vector and is fixed for the second half.  For example:

```
beta1 = ones(250,1) * 10;
beta1(1:125) = 1:125;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit example that generalizes and is verified easily to give the correct result.  Just change the definition of m0 to your 5x4 matrix:

```
%define beta variables as parameter lists:
beta1 = linspace(10,40,4);
beta2 = linspace(1,4,4);
L1    = length(beta1);
L2    = length(beta2);

%define m0 as your 5x4 matrix:
m0 = @(b1,b2)[b1, b2, 0 ; 0, 0, 0];
m = zeros(size(m0(1,1)));
[nrows,ncols] = size(m);

for q1 = 1:L1
    for q2 = 1:L2

        rows = (1:nrows) + (q2-1)*nrows;
        cols = (1:ncols) + (q1-1)*ncols;
        m(rows,cols) = m0(beta1(q1),beta2(q2));
    end
end

m0(10,1)
m
```